# obtener variable con js y enviarlas por ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

tengo unos links que los creo desde una base de datos; recorro todos los registros y los muestros. Ahora necesito enviar el `id` del `recurso` del cual se está presionando el boton, mediante AJAX para saber con cuál `recurso` estoy trabajando.

```html
<div id="Crecursos">
  <?php
    require('connect.php');
    foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM recurso') as $fila) {
     <div>
       <a href='#' class='delete'>Eliminar</a>
       <a href='#' class='edit'>Editar</a>
       <input type='text' class='delete' value='".$fila['id']."'>
     </div>
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Este es el código AJAX pero solo me manda el último `id` mostrado del código anterior.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Crecursos").on('click','.delete',function(){
      var id=document.getElementsByClassName('delete').value;
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "inc/deleteResource.php",
        data: { id:id },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#resultado').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Un pequeño esquema de lo que necesito, si por ejemplo al presionar un boton (ED/BO) del recuadro `ID1`; se debería enviar el `id` (en este caso 1) mediante AJAX. Sin embargo al presionar un botón de cualquier recuadro siempre me envía el último `id` de mis registros.
`---------   ---------`
`|  ID1  |   |  ID2  |`
`|ED   BO|   |ED   BO|`
`---------   ---------`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a crearte una función que obtenga todos esos values en un array y la invocas en la llamada ajax:

```
function getValues(){
    var values = [];
    var inputs = $('input.delete');
    $.each(inputs,function(){
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    return values;
}
```

y en tu llamada ajax:

```
data: { id:getValues() },
```

Luego recoges los valores y ya trabajas con ellos como quieras.

Te pongo el ejemplo de la función aquí para que lo veas "in situ":

```js
function getValues(){
    var values = [];
    var inputs = $('input.delete');
    $.each(inputs,function(){
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    return values;
}


var a = getValues();
$('#resultado').text(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="delete" value="123">
<input class="delete" value="124">
<input class="delete" value="hola">
<input class="delete" value="">
<input class="delete" value="-2">

<br>
<br>
<div>Tus valores: <span id="resultado"></span></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Si quieres solo borrar el id del botón que presionas:

```
$('a.delete').click(function(){
    var valor = $(this).siblings('input').val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "inc/deleteResource.php",
       data: { id:valor},
       success: function(data) {
         $('#resultado').html(data);
       }
    });
});
```

Con [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) apuntas solo a los hermanos y con el selector "input" solo a aquellos que sean inputs. Esto lo he hecho así por la forma en que has escrito tu código. No obstante, yo cambiaría la clase del link y pondría otra que no fuese la misma que tus inputs (delete). Si "ordenas" un poquito mejor el código, podrás utilizar solo una unica función ajax que te gestione todo (borrado de uno o de todos los elementos).

Ten en cuenta que esto es sólo para responder tu duda. Pero ahora tienes que tener en cuenta una cosa y es que en la anterior llamada ajax (enviar todos los id) los valores son un array que contiene todos los id's. Con este ultimo codigo, el valor no es un array de un elemento sino que es directamente un valor (numerico, string, etc...). Es también otro motivo para que tengas en cuenta el parrafo anterior y "reordenes" todo tu codigo un poquito.

Una idea es que hagas lo siguiente:

- Una función que te recoja bien todos los id's o bien sólo un único id: por ejemplo algo asi como:

funcion getValues(id):

```
function getValues(id){
    if(id){
       //que te devuelva solo el id que le pasas
    }
    else{
       //que te devuelva todos.
    }
}
```

en el html y eventos click:

- a los links les pones una clase tipo "eliminar-id" que te invoque la funcion getValues(id) pasandole como parámetro el id a eliminar.
- con el boton o botones que quieres que recoja todos los id's, le(s) pones otra clase tipo "eliminar" o "eliminar-todos" e invocas la misma funcion pero sin pasarle parámetro alguno. Esto te devolverá todos los id.
- En tu función "getValues", sea uno o todos los id's, que te los devuelva siempre como un array. Si es sólo un id el que quieres que te devuelva, pues que te devuelva un array de un elemento (el id que quieres, en este caso).

En tu fichero "deleteResource.php" siempre esperaras un array de n valores (uno o todos). Y ya a partir de ahí trabajas como quieras.

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, por lo menos ahora me envía todos los `id` de mis registro; habrá manera de que sólo envíe el `id` del botón que presiono. Estoy abierto a sugerencias.